# scoring on a scale of 1-100

Tags: dataset, gamma-distribution

I have a data set having 2000 elements. I found the distribution of that data set as Gamma (0.4). I am trying to give scores to these numbers on 1-100 scale. but I think linear conversion formulas will not work since it has a statistical distribution. How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question and has no clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

most common practice is to use true bayesian calculation 
check this out: 
http://web.archive.org/web/20100810093827/http://www.wowwebdesigns.com/formula.php

Comment: The link in this question was broken (domain parking page), so I edited it into an Internet Archive link. Is there a better replacement?